# Ansible - how to make task fail based on specific output

Tags: ansible, ansible-template

Hi I have a task which requires ftp a file from remote box to ansible controlled machine.I am using expect based FTP,so want the ansible to fail if file does not exist on the remote box.Following is my code. I am using a register variable.But i dont see the debug displaying the register contents.

```
     - name: copy files remote
       shell: |
         set timeout 1000
         spawn ftp {{ buildIP }}

         expect ":"
         send "{{ build_user }}\n"

    expect "ssword:"
    send "{{ build_password }}\n"

    expect "ftp>"
    send "get {{ build_path }} /root/Desktop/Sanity/{{  TID }}/{{ Image_dir }}/{{ build_filename }}\n"

    expect "ftp>"
    send "quit\n"

    set multiPrompt {[#$]}
    expect -re $multiPrompt
    exit 0
  args:
    executable: /usr/bin/expect
  register: shell_output
  tags: copy_source_code
- debug:
    var: shell_output.stdout_lines
```

Comment: "i don't see the debug display the register contents" ... and instead you see what? Also, I hope dearly that your yaml file is not **really** indented like that, otherwise of course you won't see anything

Comment: I dont see debug as task as listed  "shell_result.stdout_lines": [
        "1",
        "10.106.81.102_46_1_a_P101_main.info",
        "10.217.204.80_48_6_P10_main.info",
        "10.220.225.4_65_1_P2_main.info",
        "10.71.137.55_cfiles",
        "10.71.137.9_cfiles",
        "17.138.8.10.pl",
        "17.138.8.12.pl",
        "17.138.8.1.pl",
        "17.138.8.2.pl",
        "17.138.8.3.pl",
        "17.138.8.4.pl",
        "17.138.8.6.pl",
        "17.138.8.7.pl",
        "17.138.8.8.pl",
     } debug is not getting played

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using get_url for fetching files from FTP instead of expect,It will show whether the task failed or succeeded in the play recap

example play:

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - name: FTP Download
      get_url: url=ftp://username:password@localhost/file.zip dest=/tmp
      register: get_url_result
```

if the file is not present in the FTP server, output will be similar to this:

> PLAY RECAP ********************************************************
>
> localhost                  : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0
>   failed=1

In the task error details you can find the "not found" error as well